# An example on star-refinement

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$ are covers of a topological space $X$, we say,  $\mathcal U$ is a refinement of $\mathcal V$ iff each $U\in\mathcal U$ is contained in some $V\in\mathcal V$; and we say, $\mathcal U$ is a star-refinement of $\mathcal V$ iff for each $U\in\mathcal U$, there is some $V\in\mathcal V$ such that $\bigcup\{‎W\in‏\mathcal{U}:W\cap U\not= ‎\emptyset‎\}\subset V$.

Every star-refinement is a refinement, but is it true that every refinement is a star-refinement?

Comment: For a simple counter example, consider when $\mathcal{U} = \mathcal{V}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a metric space, take an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ consisting of all open sets of diameter $ \leq 1$. Then the open cover consisting of all open sets of diameter $\leq 1/3$ is a star-refinement of $\mathcal{U}$, but $\mathcal{U}$ itself is not.